# Observable.doOnCompleted() after subscriber doOnCompleted() was called

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have following sample that demontrates the problem:

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    IntStream.range(0, 1_00).forEach(subscriber::onNext);
    subscriber.onCompleted();
}).doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("I'm first, but want to be second"));

observable.subscribe((i)-> {}, (e)-> System.err.println(e), ()-> System.out.println("I'm second, but want to be first"));
```

If I replace observable `doOnCompleted` with `doAfterTerminate` it works, but it has slightly different semantics.

How to achieve that subscriber `onCompleted` will be called before `doOnCompleted` on that observable ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **doFinally()**
This is the side effect method which will be called after onCompleted.

You can also refere this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44922182/7409774

Comment: As I understood from docs this is the deprecated method in favour of doAfterTerminate and so has same semantics(will be called even if error occurred), which is note desired behavior http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html