# Upload progress with RxJava, Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java

In my project, I'm using MVP design pattern, RxJava,RxAndroid and Retrofit for consuming the API calls. Currently I am looking for solutions for trying to display an upload progress while I'm sending a picture. I have seen a couple of possible implementations, but I am afraid they do not fit within my implementation. Here's how I consume the API call with the libraries I mentioned:

```
Subscription subscription = mApiService.modVideoFromVideoController(userHash, videoId, publicVideo, rate)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<ModifyVideoResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "modVideo onCompleted");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ModifyVideoResponse modifyVideoResponse) {
                        mVideosPresenter.onVideoEdited(position, publicVideo);
                    }
                });
        mCompositeSubscription.add(subscription);
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: A solution would be to emit progress updates via `onNext()` - does your API support this approach?

Comment: @Egor no, it does not. Are there any other possible solutions that would not involve the backend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2/33384551#33384551

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is use Side Effects methods.

**For progress view hide/show:**

Bind this two events with doOnSubscribe() and doFinally().
This are two operators, so we can logically bind them with RxCall.

**doOnSubscribe()** will be called, when you are attached to Subscriber.

and

**doFinaly()** will be called at the end. In any cases Success or Error.